# WinForms DataGridView behaviour similar to SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, datagridview

I'm working with `DataGridView`s in a Windows Form project.
I'd like to obtain something similar to what appens, in edit mode, in **MS SQL Server Management Studio**.

I try to explain: I've some *mandatory* columns in my datagrid and I'd like a row is added to the grid only if the values in these columns are valid.
If the value of a cell is not valid I'd like to warn the user with a message box and pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>, the incorrect row should be resetted.

I tried using `CellValidating` and `RowValidating` events, but I'm not satisfied of the result.

Can you help me?

**UPDATE**

I implemented `RowValidating` this way:

```
private void myGrid_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MandatoryColumn"].FormattedValue.ToString()))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        myGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MandatoryColumn"].ErrorText = "Mandatory";
        MessageBox.Show("Error message");
    }
    else
    {
        myGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MandatoryColumn"].ErrorText = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

When the value in the mandatory field is not valid the message box is shown and the cell is *red-dotted*, but pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> I obtain a `IndexOutOfRangeException`...
The exception is thrown only if I show the message box, commenting it the method works (but that's not the behaviour I want to achieve...)

Comment: Where is the code and why it didn't satisfy you ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta I've added some code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is explained in the following MSDN forums post: 
[DataGridView + RowValidating = Index 4 does not have a value?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/61a0474f-41d9-40f5-a14d-a2106ccd570b/)

Basically it appears to be a bug (or at least very unexpected behaviour) in the way the DataGridView handles validation - the MessageBox.Show() causing validation on a row that no longer exists.

I found that the following change to your code fixes the issue:

```
private void myGrid_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Note the check to see if the current row is dirty
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MandatoryColumn"].FormattedValue.ToString()) &&  myGrid.IsCurrentRowDirty) 
    { 
        e.Cancel = true; 
        myGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MandatoryColumn"].ErrorText = "Mandatory"; 
        MessageBox.Show("Error message"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        myGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MandatoryColumn"].ErrorText = string.Empty; 
    } 
}
```

The change is to check that the row being validated is dirty - when you press escape and remove a row it is no longer dirty so this prevents incorrectly trying to edit it.

Comment: Thank you for this precious suggestion, it works perfectly! Thanks a lot!